# Syntax to perform string operations at Azure Table using Azure Storage Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I need to learn how to perform string operations such as 'contains', 'like' and basic string operations supported by SQL through SSMS.

Here I am using Azure Storage Explorer to query Azure Tables.

I followed this link but it only provides solution to few query commands.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683669.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure Table Storage supports only a subset of OData query operations thus you won't be able to perform query operations like `contains` etc. For a list of supported query options, you may find this link useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Gaurav's answer, think about an Azure table as a very simple data structure where only very efficient queries are allowed. The table is indexed alphabetically, so you can query by prefix or by a range of prefixes. But a "contains" query would require a full table scan because there's no way to narrow it down by prefix, so it is not allowed.